# Display image from MySQL database in a UITableView iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, uitableview, image, uiimageview

I have some image data stored in BLOB format in MySQL database,
I fetch the string and integer data but for image it does not display.
 i also tried using a `UIImageView` but it doesn't work.

Can some one please post some code to display the image data in a `UITableView`.
`NSData`-->`UIImage`-->image display.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given a NSData object `data` where the data is a UIImage supported image type (PNG, JPG, ...)

```
/* These two are what I assume you start with */
char *rawData = [self getRawDataFromDB];
int rawDataLength = [self getLengthOfRawData];

/* To convert that to an image... */
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:rawDataLength]];
```

Once you have the image, then add to your UITableViewDataSource's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[[cell imageView] setImage: image];
```

Comment: after database fetching in result
i did

for(NSDictionary *row in result)
{
  [tableData addObject:[row objectForKey:@"imgdata"]];
}

and in the table view method

[cell.imageView setImage:[tableData objectAtIndex:index]];

where to place your code can  you Explain

Comment: You could put it in either place, but you need to convert the [row objectForKey:@"imgdata"] (which is the rawData) to a UIImage.  I'd put it in the database fetch routine as [tableData addObject:image].

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.how to convert rawdata to get image??can you explain with piece of coding...